# MP4 - Read audio block

Tags: audio, header, mp4

I want to read just the sound block in MP4 file.
Does somebody knows how the MP4 file built? How can I find the headers in the file?
How does the header built?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

These two will give you a head start:
http://www.jiscdigitalmedia.ac.uk/guide/aac-audio-and-the-mp4-media-format
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/video/articles/mp4_movie_atom.html

I am trying to do the same thing and right now I am stuck at not being able to open the individual chunks.